# Trying to use word2Vec on file but not working?

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec

Hello I am new in word2vec so I was trying a simple program to read file and get the vec of each word, but there's something wrong with the tokenization process, as word2vec takes into account each letter not word!

for instance my file contains "hello this is my first trial"

```
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize


F = open('testfile')
f=F.read()
doc= word_tokenize(f)
print(f)

print(doc)

model = Word2Vec(doc,min_count=1)

# summarize the loaded model
print(model)

words = list(model.wv.vocab)
print(model['hello'])
```

I get an error that hello is not in the vocab, but when i use a letter 'h' it works

Comment: What does `doc` print?

Comment: a list of the file content ['hello', 'this','is','my','first','trial'] @ShlomiF

Answer (score 1):

Word2Vec works on sequences of texts, where each text is a list-of-string-tokens. You're providing a single document, so it will see that as a text of `['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']`, then a text of `['t', 'h', 'i', 's']`, etc.

As a result, the only 'words' it will learn are single letters. (Look at `model.wv.index2entities` to see this.)

Putting your single `doc` into a list-of-docs would be a quickie workaround. For example:

```
docs = [doc]
model = Word2Vec(doc, min_count=1)
```

However, also note that Word2Vec doesn't work well on toy-sized examples. It requires large, varied training texts to create useful vectors. For example, to just support vectors of the default 100-dimensions of gensim's `Word2Vec`, you should have training material with 10,000+ unique words, and 5+ varied uses of each word.

So you can run a tiny example like you're trying here just to make sure you have code that runs and understand the interfaces, but don't expect the results to be useful yet.

Take a look at the tutorial notebook included in the gensim `docs/notebooks` directory for a slightly-more-realistic-sized learning example. It's also viewable online at:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/word2vec.ipynb